# Como exibir dinamicamente o nome da categoria do meu post dentro do texto no wordpress

Tags: php, html, wordpress, dinâmico

Qual função PHP posso usar para que, no texto do meu post, apareça o nome da categoria dinamicamente no wordpress?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the_category() costuma funcionar pra mim. Ela retorna a lista das categorias vinculadas ao post já com os links.

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_category